# Proof of limit using epsilon-L proof

Tags: calculus

We have $\lim \frac{n+6}{n^2-6}=0$. I need to prove this limit using the epsilon-L proof method.

I wrote down the following proof:

$\dfrac{n+6}{n^2-6}<\dfrac{2n}{\frac{1}{2}n^2}=\dfrac{4}{n}<\epsilon$ (why are we allowed to say this?) so $n>\dfrac{4}{\epsilon}$.

Proof. Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $N=\max\{4,\dfrac{4}{\epsilon}\}$ (since the inequality is only valid for $n>6$ right? Since $n+6<2n$ gives $n>6$ and $n^2-6>\frac{1}{2}n^2$ gives $n>4$)?? I don't understand this too.

Can anyone clarify? I can't seem to understand anything about this *** proof

Comment: For $n>4$ we have that $$\frac{4}{n}>\frac{n+6}{n^2-6}$$ That's why there is the $N=\max\{4,\frac{4}{\epsilon}\}$

Comment: @kingw3 what is this guy doing at 2:40? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb9vQ16Tm1M is there a quick way to find that 4?

Comment: Why are we allowed to say $\displaystyle \frac{n+6}{n^2-6}< \displaystyle \frac{4}{n}< \epsilon?$. Well, for a given $\epsilon$ we want to make the LHS less than $\epsilon$. So for what values of $n$ can we achieve this? To find that particular $N \in \Bbb N$ we consider it to be less than $\epsilon$ and then find $N$

Comment: We want to take $N$ so big that $(n+6)/(n^2-6) < \epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. We could try to find the exact value of $N$ where this starts to happen by solving $u(n) := (n+6)/(n^2-6) = \epsilon$ for $n$ as expression of $\epsilon$. In this case it's not that difficult since we get an equation of second degree. But often it's difficult to solve the equation exactly. Therefore we find an expression $s(n)$ with a bigger value (i.e. $s(n) > u(n)$) so that when $s(n)<\epsilon$ we also have $u(n)<\epsilon$, but that makes it easier to solve for $n$.

Comment: But I do agree that the first inequality, $(n+6)/(n^2-6) < (2n)/(n^2/2)$, requires $n>6$ for the numerator, so we should take $N=\max\{6,4/\epsilon\}$.

Comment: @md2perpe wow that last sentence really cleared it up for me ! Thanks! Can you explain why we need the $\max\{6,\frac{4}{\epsilon}\}$ in place?

Comment: We need to have $N>6$ and we need to have $N>4/\epsilon$. Thus we take $N > \max\{6,4/\epsilon\}$.

Comment: You have not stated what   $n$  is approaching  :  $\lim_{n\to ??}(n+6)/(n^2-6)$

Answer (score 0):

For $n>6$, we have

$$n^2-6 >n^2-36>0$$
$$n^2-36=(n+6)(n-6) $$
thus

$$\frac {n+6}{n^2-6}<\frac {1}{n-6} $$

To satisfy $\frac {n+6}{n^2-6}<\epsilon $, it sufficient to have
$n>6$ and $\frac {1}{n-6}<\epsilon $

or $n>6$ and $n>6+\frac {1}{\epsilon} $

so we will take $N=6+\frac {1}{\epsilon} $.